# How to import database using MongoDB Compass?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to import data to my MongoDB Compass database and I get keep getting an error stating that  `"/data/db/: is a directory."`

I'm using this mongoimport code provided by Mongodb:

```
mongoimport --uri mongodb+srv://tesalon_22:<PASSWORD>@myflixdb.gk5cp.mongodb.net/<DATABASE> --collection <COLLECTION> --type <FILETYPE> --file <FILENAME>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can import data from a file (CSV, JSON or TSV types) into a collection. See: [Import and Export Data - Compass](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/import-export/). Or, you can import the same data using the command-line utility [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongoimport/index.html).